# Javascript error : catChildNotes[y].setAttribute is not an function

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

So, I have some JavaScript code which I test with Greasemonkey locally. But I get this persistent error in the Firefox Error Console:

> catChildNotes[y].setAttribute is not an function

Code:

```js
var i = prompt("How many videos have you got?", "");
function remove_mp4()
{
   titleElems=document.getElementsByName("title");
   for(i=0; i<titleElems.length; i++)
   {
      titleInner=titleElems[i].innerHTML;
      titleElems[i].innerHTML=titleInner.replace(titleInner.match(".mp4"), "");
   }
}
for (var x = 0; x < i; i++)
{
    document.getElementsByName("description")[x].value = "Visit me on my web-site :\
    \
                                                          http://www.sample.com/";
    document.getElementsByName("keywords")[x].value = prompt("Enter keywords : ","");
    catChildNodes=document.getElementsByName("category")[x].childNodes;
    catChildNodes[x + 1].removeAttribute("selected");
    for(y=0; y<catChildNodes.length; y++)
{
       if(catChildNodes[y].value="27") 
   {
          catChildNodes[y].setAttribute("selected",""); 
   }
}
}
remove_mp4();
```

This script should be run on Youtube upload page and do the following :

- Remove ".mp4" from the title
- Add default description
- Add keywords (which are equal to the prompt value)
- Change category to "Education"

Comment: The chances are that `catChildNodes[y]` is not what you think it is and the property `setAttribute` is evaluating to `undefined` .. so what *does* `catChildNodes[y]` evaluate to? Why?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you explain a little bit better, please?

Comment: It evaluates to name proprety in an HTML element of the web-page. Name attribute is set to "category", so it finds it and get's it's value. It's index is var x, because x is growing, so if I have like 10 videos, x would first be 0, then it would be 9, changing all of my videos category to "Education". Hope I explained good! :)

Comment: you would `console.log(catChildNodes[y])` just before the `.setAttribute` call to see what it evaluates to. You would then work your way up this way until the source of the bug is found and whoopsie-doo the problem is solved.

Comment: It evaluates to "object Text" and "object HTMLOptionElement". I can put a website code if that would help. :)

Comment: "object Text" looks suspicious. It looks like a non-DOM Node .. a live demonstration (jsfiddle) would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you get the child nodes of an element you will get other [element nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element) and [text nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/text). The former have a `setAttribute` method, the latter don't (simply because text nodes don't have any attributes). If you need only the element children and no the text nodes then you should use [`children` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.children) instead of `childNodes`.

There is at least one more bug in your code, this is not a comparison:

```js
if (catChildNodes[y].value = "27")
```

This will *assign* the value 27 to `catChildNodes[y].value`. If you actually want to compare then you should use the comparison operator:

```js
if (catChildNodes[y].value == "27")
```